# Regular expression using + problem in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regular expression. In phone validation, i have to use the "+" sign in that.  How to provide the + sign in regular expression.  Because + sign indicates one or more of preceding character(s). Whether i will provide like this `\+` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it with a preceding `\` like:

```
/^\+\d+$/
```

This example does only match strings that start with a `+` that is followed by one or more digits.

Answer (score 4):

As a pretty much universal rule with regex engines, you can escape metacharacters with a backslash, so that while `+` by itself indicates "1 or more", `\+` is just a plus sign.

Answer (score 3):

Escape it with a `\`?