# Regex for remove everything after | (with | )

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I was trying to find a solution for my problem.

Input:

```
This is the sample title | mypcworld
```

Output:

```
This is the sample title
```

I want to remove everything comes after " | " using simple regex on notepad++
It seems to be really simple one. But I was tried with some other regex "|.*$" listed on here, but no luck. The problem was the character "|" was alteration equivalent of or.
So please help me to solve it.

Comment: How about use a backslash `\\` in front of the pipe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression matching special character as literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035161/regular-expression-using-problem-in-js)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that special character question question. Thanks.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The pipe, `|`, is a special-character in regex (meaning "or") and you'll have to escape it with a `\`.

Using your current regex:

```
\|.*$
```

I've tried this in Notepad++, as you've mentioned, and it appears to work well.

Comment: For some reason this gives me the complete OPPOSITE of what the question is asking... ???

Comment: @Radioactive, the question is asking about "removing" everything after the `|` in Notepad++. If you Ctrl+H (for find + replace), enter my suggestion here in the "Find what" field and use an empty string for the "Replace with" field, make sure "Regular expression" is selected and click the "Replace" button, it should work as described. I just tested again and 7 years later, it still works =]

Answer (score 17):

If you want to get everything after `|` excluding set character use this code.

```
[^|]*$
```

**Others solutions `\|.*$`**

```
Results : | mypcworld
```

**This one `[^|]*$`**

```
Results : mypcworld
```

http://regexr.com/3elkd

Comment: [^|]*$ this worked very well for me. Why doesn't ^.*$ work, though? It specifies it can start and end with any character "." but it doesn't find anything, at least for my AegiSub program

Answer (score 7):

In a `.txt` file opened with Notepad++,
press <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>
go in the tab "Replace"
write the regex pattern `\|.+` in the space **Find what**
and let the space **Replace with** blank

Then tick the choice **matches newlines** after the choice **Regular expression**
and press two times on the **Replace** button

Comment: in Notepad++, CRTL+H will directly go to "Replace" tab so instead of CRTL+F and changing to "Replace" tab - one can use that one.