# Remove parts of filename with regex

Tags: regex

I have a few hundreds files with names like:

```
DDS vol.001 Some Name (bs.) Title (Non-important text).txt
DDS vol.002 Some Other Name (bs.) Title (Non-imp text)(other non-imp text).txt
etc.
```

I have a bulk rename software that supports regex so how can I use regex to rename them like this:

```
DDS vol.001 Title.txt
DDS vol.002 Title.txt
etc.
```

I tried to use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367373/regex-for-remove-everything-after-with) but instead of `|` (bar character) I used `(Non` but is not changing anything so I don't know what am I doing wrong

Comment: This is not a coding service. What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @Bohemian I tried to use this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367373/regex-for-remove-everything-after-with) but instead of '|' (bar character) I used '(Non'  () but is not changing anything so I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your pattern, something like this should work:

- Search for `(.*[0-9+]).*\) (.*) \(.*\)(.*)$`
- Replace with `$1 $2$3`

[image]