# How to match a regex, removing everything after the match

Tags: php, regex

Say I have the following: `preg_match("/ESP[0-9]?[0-9]/", $devid)`

I want to match data such as the following:
`$devid = "ESP1"`
`$devid = "ESP10"`
`$devid = "ESP78"`

However, I don't want the string to contain anything that isn't matched in the regex. For example:
`$devid = "ESP100"` would return `ESP10`
`$devid = "ESP10234234"` would return `ESP10`
`$devid = "ESP78hello"` would return `ESP78`

...and if there isn't a match, returning null (or equivalent).

In a way, I want to detect where preg_match finishes, and then remove the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for remove everything after | (with | )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367373/regex-for-remove-everything-after-with)

Comment: @SamSwift웃 That question is more based on the regex, over a PHP problem

Comment: What is wrong with your current regex? Pass a third argument named e.g. `$matches` and access its zero index `echo $matches[0]`

Comment: @revo Looks like I missed that, it's what I was looking for and seems the simplest way to the problem. Feel free to make an answer I can accept.

Comment: Please check @cars10m's answer.

Comment: It is definitely possible using `$match[0]` but that would be taking bit of PHP help to get the job done instead of doing it completely in regex

Comment: @anubhava Yes and the first approach is the simplest.

Comment: ...I'd personally say @revo's approach is simpler to understand when reading the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a third argument in [`preg_match`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like:

```
preg_match('/ESP\d\d?/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0] ?? NULL);
```

In case nothing is found `NULL` will be output.

Edit(cars10m):
From testing in rextester.com I found that $matches is returned as an array of length 0, when nothing is found, see here: http://rextester.com/UUM57869

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_replace` with a capture group:

```
$devid = preg_replace('/^(ESP\d{1,2}+).+/', '$1', $devid);
```

This regex matches & captures the text that we want to keep in group #1 and in replacement we put back `$1`.

or without the capture group use match reset `\K`:

```
$devid = preg_replace('/^ESP\d{1,2}+\K.+/', '', $devid);
```

This regex matches text that we want to keep and then using `\K` we reset match info. In replacement we just use empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jddL8v/2)

Note that `{1,2}+` matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, **without giving back**.

Comment: Hm, using `$devid = preg_replace('/^(ESP\d{1,2}).+/', '$1', $devid);` if I pass in "ESP10" then it's only returning "ESP1". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the word boundary `\b`.

```
preg_match("/\bESP\d{1,2}\b/", $devid, $match);
```

The word boundary makes sure it matches a word that starts with ESP and ends with one or two digits.