# Regex for removing characters after "/" in MongoDB (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I have some strings such as following (example strings)

- wm16s772Ön/10
- wm 16 s- 772Ön !/10
- wm 16_s772Ön:/10

I want to  clean the characters so that they appear as following

```
wm16s772Ön
```

In **mongodb** I used the following way

```
print({doc}.title.replace(/[^0-9a-zäöåÄÖÅéÉæÆøØßẞüÜ]/gi,"").toLowerCase())
```

or simply

```
print("wm 16 s- 772Ön !/10 ".replace(/[^0-9a-zäöåÄÖÅéÉæÆøØßẞüÜ]/gi,"").toLowerCase())
```

Which gives me wm16s772Ön10

How can modify the regex so it removes all the characters after / inclusively so the result is the following

```
wm16s772Ön
```

Please note when it comes to the code (.replace), I will not be able to modify that. It is only the regex part that I can modify

Comment: Add `(\/.+$)|` at the start of the expression, this will match a forward slash and following characters until the end of the string. The `|` is the OR operator. So it matches /... or the negated set.

Comment: @ChrisG, while other answers were good as well, yours was correct and also matching the style of regex in question. So i will use yours as the selected answer. Can you please  create it as an answer so i can select it ?

Comment: @Shahan You do not need a capturing group in the pattern. Nor do you need `$` after `.*`, this pattern greedily matches up to the line end.

Answer (score 0):

The regex will like:

Match `/` and any characters

```
print({doc}.title.replace(/\/.+/gi,"").toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367430/9002484)

In your case you can use `/\/.*/gi`

```
"wm 16 s- 772Ön !/10 ".replace(/\/.*/gi,"").toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
.replace(/\/.*|[^0-9a-zäöåÄÖÅéÉæÆøØßẞüÜ]/gi, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpBZmT/1).

*Details*:

- `\/.*` - a `/` and then the rest of the line
- `|` - or
- `[^0-9a-zäöåÄÖÅéÉæÆøØßẞüÜ]` - any char other than an ASCII letter / digit or the extended letters from the set.

Note the order of the alternatives matters here, as the first one "wins" and the other is not tried if the first one matches. That is also why you cannot quantify the `[^0-9a-zäöåÄÖÅéÉæÆøØßẞüÜ]` part, as this pattern matches a `/` char.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't need any `/` characters in the result, you can compose the regex after the very words you use in English: "match the first occurring `/` and anything that's after it". This would be:

```
/\/.*$/
```

A little explanation:

```
/     start a new regex
\/    match "/" character literally
.*    match any amount of any character
$     match the end of the input (this one is optional)
/     end the regex
```

Then you just put it in the `.replace` call:

```js
"wm16s772Ön/10".replace(regex, "")
// returns "wm16s772Ön"

"wm 16 s- 772Ön !/10".replace(regex, "")
// returns "wm 16 s- 772Ön !"

"wm 16_s772Ön:/10".replace(regex, "")
// returns "wm 16_s772Ön:"
```